# Match on a list of field value combinations in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a list of tuples of values, like this:

```
[("a1", "b1", "b1"), ("a2", "b2", "b3")... ("a_n", "b_n", "c_n")]
```

These are sets of values for fields "a", "b", and "c" that I'd like to use to match documents in elasticsearch. How can I do this type of multi-field terms query where matches must happen in sets as defined above?

**Edit:**

I tried using a bool query like so:

```
query={   
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [{
                    "bool": {
                        "must":[
                            {"term": {"a": a_val}},
                            {"term": {"b": b_val}},
                            {"term": {"c": c_val}}
                        ]
                    }
                }
                for (a_val, b_val, c_val) in identifiers
            ]
        },
    },
}

es.search('my_index', body=query)
```

but this resulted in:

```
TransportError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'failed to create query:...
```

I also tried a simpler version of the bool query but got the exact same error:

```
query = {   
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {"term": {"a": "a1"}},
                {"term": {"b": "b1"}},
                {"term": {"c": "c1"}}     
            ]
        },
    },
}

es.search('my_index', body=query)
```

What am I doing wrong with these bool queries?

Comment: I think [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html#query-dsl-bool-query) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah along with bool query you also have to model your data a bit. You might need nested datatype. Take a look at nested datatype

Answer (score 0):

If possible you should index them into a single `keyword` field with a separator like `a1-b1-c1` etc. and then use a single `terms` filter with the array of values you are looking for.